# parse trigger beforeSave when using object as pointer

Tags: android, parse-platform

i have some code like this:

```
ParseObject firstObject = ParseObject.create("oneClass");
//ParseObject secondObject = already exist on cloude - AnotherClass;
firstObject.put("pointer",secondObject);
firstObject.saveInBackground();
```

`SecondClass` `beforeSave & afterSave` triggered from some reason...
any idea?

Comment: So you update a field for an object in your class and you expect `beforeSave` and `afterSave` not to be called ??!

Comment: He was expecting that on the second object's class.

Comment: if i save one class object, why another class object triggered?

Comment: saving an object that is related to other unsaved objects will save them, too.  (this is probably better documented somewhere else, but see the section on relational data here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-relational-data.  Note the comment in the first code block before the save)

Comment: second object already saved. this is not the case u talk about

Answer (score 0):

When you save an object that has pointers attached to it, those pointers are also saved. This can be useful, or it can cause problems where your saves time out because you're calling extra beforeSave triggers. You just have to be aware of it and plan accordingly.

Also, FYI, when you query for objects that have fields that contain pointers, the pointers that are returned are empty pointers, i.e. they just contain the objectId. If you want to access them, use the `include` method of your query so that those objects are fetched as well.